# Discord bot does not send a message about a kick

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have a certain problem and I don't understand how to solve it. I am writing a discord bot through the snake library.
At the moment I am creating moderation commands (inter is ctx).

```
@bot.command(description='Данная команда исключает пользователя из сервера')
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True, administrator=True)
async def kick(inter, member: disnake.Member, *, reason='Нарушение правил сервера'):
    await inter.respond(f"{inter.author.mention} исключил пользователя {member.mention}")
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await inter.message.delete()
```

When executing the kick command, the bot does not write a message, what could this be related to?

I tried to create new methods of sending messages, went through a lot of ways, but nothing came up.

Comment: [How to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some issues with your code. Since you're using the disnake library, I'll provide you with the corrected code for your kick command in Python. The issue seems to be with the usage of await inter.message.send. In disnake, you should use await inter.respond to send a message from a command interaction. Here's the corrected code:

```
from disnake.ext import commands

@bot.command(description='Данная команда исключает пользователя из сервера')
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True, administrator=True)
async def kick(inter, member: disnake.Member, *, reason='Нарушение правил сервера'):
    await inter.respond(f"{inter.author.mention} исключил пользователя {member.mention}")
    await member.kick(reason=reason)

# The rest of your code for other moderation commands...
```

Make sure you have imported the necessary modules and set up your bot properly before using these commands. Additionally, ensure that the bot has the necessary permissions to perform these actions (e.g., kick_members).

Comment: unfortunately this did not fix the problem

Comment: what is your bug? commented at

Comment: Sorry, man, I'm just a complete dumbass. The problem wasn't in the code. Instead of writing commands on behalf of the bot, I used the built-in discord commands without noticing it, I'm so stupid and inattentive that I'm still in shock. Do you know how to disable the built-in discord commands?

Comment: ok so use this:
`import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot{bot.user.name} login)

@bot.command()
async def سلام(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi!')

bot.run('your tokenا')
`